# GWT.create(MyClass.class) gives Error that MyClass must be a class

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to call a RemoteService from my EntryPoint Class. 
However, I get the Error in GWT.create(). I am passing the client side interface for my service. I am getting the error that it must be a class.

19: `private LoginServiceAsync loginServiceAsync = GWT.create(LoginService.class);`

[ERROR] Line 19: Rebind result 'com.example.client.LoginService' must be a class

Here is my code for LoginService in the client folder:

```
package com.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("LoginService")
public interface LoginService  {
    boolean signUpUser(String name, String email, String password);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GWT.create(MyClass.class)` looks first for replacement- or generate-with rules. If GWT does not find a rule, it will do a `new MyClass()`.

Because you did not extend `RemoteService`, GWT does not find the generate-with-rule and tries a `new`.

That's why you got this error.

Comment: Thanks, for you explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my Interface was not extending RemoteService.

```
package com.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("LoginService")
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {
    boolean signUpUser(String name, String email, String password);
}
```

Solved my problem,
Also I had to change this in the LoginServiceAsync:

```
void signUpUser(String name, String email, String password,com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback<java.lang.Boolean> arg4);
```

Not sure why this works, Can anyone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: First, you should use the Maven/Gradle task to generate Async interfaces and not roll your own. Second, the answer from [El Hoss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57196382/2071828) explains why you must extends the right interface.